# Configuring AUTH0 field in NXP NTAG216

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to configure a NTAG216 with password protection.

I'm trying to write starting protected address in AUTH0 byte, I've read the entire doc on ntag2x but I can't figure out how to do this.

If I analyze tag content I can see that AUTH0 dedicated page has .r flat, that should means it is write-protected, but how can I unlock this page?

Can someone help me or indicate an example or an android doc for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem.

The problem was I've previously inadvertenly set PWD, PACK and AUTH0, so then I can't write anymore on AUTH0 address because that address was locked.

As written in docs, that address is simply writable as a normal memory page.

With android I'm using this code to secure NTAG216

According to Michael Roland I've edited my code like this. I preferred to write de default value in the CFG1 because this code for me serves as an initialization of the tag, then I'll lock it in read and write, so it should be impossible to come to a dirt data state

```
// PWD
if (!ntag.write(0xE5, pwd.getBytes(CHARSET))) {
    showToastMex("ERROR IN WRITING PWD");
    retValue = false;
}

// PACK
if (retValue) {
    byte[] empty = {0x00, 0x00};
    byte[] completePack = ArrayUtils.addAll(pack.getBytes(HbgHelper.CHARSET), empty);
    if (!ntag.write(0xE6, completePack)) {
        showToastMex("ERROR IN WRITING PACK");
        retValue = false;
    }
}

// PROT (enable read and write password protection from AUTH0 ADDRESS
if (success) {
    byte accessCfg = (byte)Integer.parseInt("10000000", 2);
    byte[] cfg2 = {accessCfg, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    if (!ntag.write(0xE4, cfg2)) {
        showToast("ERROR IN WRITING PROT");
        success = false;
    }
 }

// AUTH0 (from page 220 = DCh)
if (retValue) {
    byte[] toWrite = {(byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, HbgHelper.LOCK_MEM_ADDR_START};
    if (!ntag.write(0xE3, toWrite)) {
        showToastMex("ERROR IN WRITING AUTH0");
        retValue = false;
    }
}
```

where

```
MEM_ADDR_TO_LOCK = (byte) 0xDC
```

and

```
CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8")
```

Comment: You certainly do not want to write a space character (which probably translates to 0x20 depending on your CHARSET) to the first three bytes of the CFG1 page (0xE3). Instead you should either read the existing value and use that value in the write operation, or you should set those values to the default values (i.e. use `byte[] toWrite = {(byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, MEM_ADDR_TO_LOCK};`). Similarly, for the PACK value, you should **never** write the upper two bytes with any other value than 0x00.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll follow your suggestion but i can't figure out how you determined default value for CFG1. As soon as possible I'll update answer code according to your suggestions

Comment: The default value is described in the [manual (see pages 18-19)](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf).